# Передача принятых значений из php-файла в другой php-файл

Tags: php

Нестандартная ситуация. Получаем множество значений из формы в php-обработчик, затем там проделываем с ними какие-то вещи, а затем передаем их в другой php-файл, который уже вернет конечный результат. Такое возможно?

Comment: а другой файл вызывается из первого? Тогда вообще никаких проблем, он увидит переменные первого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например через GET

```
 header('Location: randomfile.php?variable1=value1&variable2=val2');
```

Или через механизм сессий

Первый скрипт

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['variable1'] = 'value1';
header('Location: another.php');
```

Второй скрипт

```
session_start(); 
$variable1 = $_SESSION['variable1'];
```